# Restrict telnet access on Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS using username/password

Tags: 16.04, telnet

I have telnet (without creds) enabled on multiple ports on my ubuntu due to an application running on it.
Can you guide me on how to add a username/password for multiple ports listening for telnet .

Comment: Please provide more details. What is listening for telnet connections on those ports? Is it the application you mentioned? If so, then the only way to add user/password authorization is in this application.

Comment: Yes it's the application that spins up multiple telnet process on demand. I was hoping to find a way put a default username/password for for all incoming tcp connections..maybe mimic what a console server does .

Comment: Does not seem possible to do this outside of the application. The application needs to be modified to include authentication natively.